# I want to find the xpath for day separated by <br>

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML like this

```
<td class="FormLabel" valign="top">
  <span class="DataLabel">Consists of:</span>
</td>
<td class="FormData">
  <span class="BodyText">
    Sunday<br>
    Monday<br>
  </span>
</td>
```

Here I want Xpath to just check for Sunday.

I had written Xpath like this

```
//span[contains(.,'Consis')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td/span[contains(.,'Sun')]
```

But this is not working as it is showing both days sunday and monday.
Help me with finding sunday or any particular day for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sunday

```
//span[contains(.,'Consis')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td/span[contains(.,'Sun')]/text()[1]
```

respectively, [2] is monday

Below part, containing sunday

```
//span[contains(.,'Consis')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td/span/text()[contains(.,'Sun')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Select *text* node instead of *span* -

```
 //span[contains(.,'Consis')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td/text()[contains(.,'Sun')]
```

Comment: I am using Xpath Checker. Here it is not retrieving any day. I think the approach used by @splash58 would be useful here. i.e. give node numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[@class='FormData']//text()[preceding-sibling::br][1]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.